# How to prove perfectness of semidirect product of Lie algebras?

Tags: lie-algebras

Consider a semisimple Lie algebra S and a vector space V - considered as Abelian Lie algebra - with a non-zero irreducible representation $$\rho: S \rightarrow End(V).$$
$L$ and $V$ are finite-dimensional over the base field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Then the semidirect product
$$L:= V \rtimes_\rho S$$
is a perfect Lie algebra, i.e. $[L,L]=L$.

- How to prove this result?

Comment: Hints: What is $[S,S]$? What is $[S,V]$? conclusion?

Comment: @YCor I know $[S,S]=S$ and $[S,V]=V$. But given $(v,s)\in L$ and knowing $s=[s_1,s_2]$ how to find $v_1,v_2\in V$ with $\rho(s_1)(v_2)-\rho(s_2)(v_1)=v$?

Comment: check out the definition of $[L,L]$: it is by definition the set of sums of elements in the image of the bracket map, not only the image itself. So the problem is easier than you thought.

Comment: @YCor I apologize, but even with your hint I do not recognize the solution: My problem is the representation of a given element $v\in V$ by using fixed(!) elements $s_i$ from L.

Comment: No, your problem is "how to prove that $L$ is a perfect Lie algebra" (which means that every element is a sum of finitely many commutators). If your problem is whether every element of $L$ is a single commutator, or anything else, this is more difficult and you should edit your question.

Comment: @YCor I agree: My problem is perfectness, which means to represent an element $(v,s)$ as a sum of commutators. But to start, I assume $s=[s_1,s_2]$. How to represent an element $(v,s)$ as a sum of commutators, using $s_1$ and $s_2$?

Comment: You have $[S,S]=S$ and $[S,V]=V$, so $[S+V,S+V]=S+V$, that's it. What you're trying to prove is more complicated.

Comment: @YCor Thanks, I was lacking the equivalence of $\rho(S)(V)=V$ and $[S,V]_L=V$.

Answer (score 1):

Solution thanks to the comments of @YCor:

Assume $L=V \rtimes_{\rho}S$. Then 
$$L=V+S$$ 
with $S\subset L$ subalgebra and $V\subset L$ ideal. By definition of the commutator in $L$ holds

$$[S,S]_S=[S,S]_L.$$
Semisimpleness of $S$ implies 
$$S=[S,S]_S.$$
Moreover
$$\rho(S)(V)=[S,V]_L.$$
Irreducucibility of $\rho \neq 0$ implies 
$$V=\rho(S)(V)=[S,V]_L.$$ 
Then
$$L=S+V=[S,S]_L+[S,V]_L\subset [L,L]_L$$
The other inclusion is obvious.